# Why promise is undefined? chrome.tabs.query().then();

Tags: google-chrome-extension, es6-promise

Isn't it suppose to be defined in every built-in chrome function?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined at popup.js:23

```
var requestCurrentTabId = {
  active:true,
  windowType:"normal",
  currentWindow: true
};

function getCurrentTab(chromeOpenedTabsList){
  window.currentTabId = chromeOpenedTabsList[0].id;

  //Connect to the content_script messaging port
  //on the current opened page, the extension user is visiting.
  var messagePassingPort = chrome.tabs.connect(currentTabId, {name: "content_script_port"});

  //Inject selection listener into Chrome PDF viewer
  //after opening this popup.


  console.log("Current tab:" + window.currentTabId);
}
//getCurrentTab - is a callback


chrome.tabs.query(requestCurrentTabId, getCurrentTab).then(console.log("Current tab2:" + window.currentTabId));
```

Comment: Chrome API does not support Promise. It's callback-based.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=promise 
Chrome supports promises since version 49, the oldest browser to have support.

Comment: Caniuse data is totally irrelevant here.

Comment: Always check the documentation: [chrome.tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query).

Comment: You can load [webextension-polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill) to use Promise with extension API in Chrome.